# MVC6 Strongly typed action links and views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

We are currently getting a new application stood up with MVC6. In previous versions, we used T4MVC so we could do stuff like:

```
@Url.Action(MVC.Home.Index);
```

and

```
return View(MVC.Home.Views.Index, model);
```

In the new application I have to use magic strings. I Hate magic strings. Are there any alternatives for this for MVC6?

Answer (score 5):

Came across this [AspNet.Mvc.TypedRouting](https://github.com/ivaylokenov/AspNet.Mvc.TypedRouting#aspnetmvctypedrouting) Repository on GitHub that I thought would be useful when I eventually move over to MVC6.

Not sure if it handles views as well though

Some instructions from the readme

To use expression based link generation, you need to do the following into your Startup class:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
   // other configuration code

   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
        routes.UseTypedRouting();
   });
}
```

Basically, you can do the following:

```
// generating link without parameters - /Home/Index
urlHelper.Action<HomeController>(c => c.Index());

// generating link with parameters - /Home/Index/1
urlHelper.Action<HomeController>(c => c.Index(1));

// generating link with additional route values - /Home/Index/1?key=value
urlHelper.Action<HomeController>(c => c.Index(1), new { key = "value" });

// generating link where action needs parameters to be compiled, but you do not want to pass them - /Home/Index
// * With.No<TParameter>() is just expressive sugar, you can pass 'null' for reference types but it looks ugly
urlHelper.Action<HomeController>(c => c.Index(With.No<int>()));
```

Comment: This looks like it fits the bill! Im going to start playing with it!

Comment: Unfortunately Views cannot be found compile time. To make strongy typed views, a Visual Studio extension is needed.